# implode assotiative array with preserving keys?

Tags: php, arrays, implode

```
$arr=array('a'=>1,'b'=>2);

echo implode(',',$arr) // returns '1,2'
```

I need to get `a=1,b=2` as result.

I know that I can get it by using `foreach` but I aware that there is a shorter way with less code.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php
$arr=array('a'=>1,'b'=>2);
echo str_replace('&', ',', http_build_query($arr));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
echo urldecode(http_build_query($arr, '', ','));
```

The third argument of `http_build_query()` is the separator, so it's not needed to use `str_replace()`

Use `urldecode()` to decode, because `http_build_query()` will urlencode the string.

Answer (score 1):

If you want more control in formatting or processing the array elements, you can try:

```
<pre>
    <?php
        $fruits = array("d" => "lemon", 
                        "a" => "orange", 
                        "b" => "banana", 
                        "c" => "apple");

        function format_list(&$list, $key)
        {
            $list = "{$key}={$list}";
        }

        echo "Starting array:\n";
        print_r($fruits);

        echo "\nModified array:\n";
        array_walk($fruits, 'format_list');
        print_r($fruits);

        echo "\nFinal string:\n";
        echo implode(',',$fruits);

    ?>
</pre>
```

I use two PHP functions, `array_walk` and `implode`, but I also needed to define a call back function, `format_list`.

Using `http_build_query` as illustrated by landons is more concise, but as in all things PHP, there are many ways of doing the same thing.

You can try the following PHP fiddle:
http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/f95-wsk